# How to send email from the custom module?

Tags: magento2, email

Guys I'm trying to create a module to send e-mail and I tried to follow this tutorial:[Tutorial](https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/sending-custom-emails-using-custom-module-in-magento-2/)
however in the end it generates an error
"Unable to send mail: Unknown error" and I don't know what to do, I need help. Has anyone done this before, can you indicate a good tutorial or something?

Comment: you have setup SMTP on your local or are you using any custom SMTP extension?

Comment: Need to configure smtp on site? did not know. I'm a beginner in magento.

Comment: even if it is in a custom module, is it necessary to configure smtp?

Comment: No in custom module you can specify details of your SMTP and it will use those. https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/ you can use you gmail details

Comment: is this extension paid?

Comment: this is my module, if you can take a look : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/336998/sending-personalized-module-email-does-not-work

Comment: that is free extension. please use it and configure it.

Comment: is it free to use in business? or just for testing

Comment: you can use in business also